# Como registrar dados em um dicionário dentro de um arquivo .txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou realizando um sistema de cadastro, o qual registra o usuário e a senha de uma pessoa em um dicionário e depois passa esse dicionário para um arquivo .txt. Veja o exemplo:

```
user = 'Lucas'
password = '1234'`

dic = {}
dic[user] = password`

import pickle
archive = open('data.txt', 'ab')
pickle.dump(dic, archive)
archive.close()`

archive = open('data.txt', 'rb')
dic = pickle.load(archive)
archive.close()
print(dic)
```

O problema é que meu programa vai registrar infinitos usuários e para sempre, então se agora eu colocasse outro usuário e outra senha ele deveria retornar um dicionário com **todos os usuários já cadastrados + o usuário que está sendo cadastrado**, ou seja, adicionar o último cadastro ao dicionário já salvo com os usuários anteriores, só que ele está salvando um dicionário **apenas** com o último usuário cadastrado. Como poderia resolver?

Comment: Você está sempre definindo um novo dicionário, `dic`. Para tal, você precisará carregar o dicionário a partir do arquivo antes de inserir o novo cadastro.

Comment: Como poderia realizar isso Woss?

Comment: Você já fez isso no código, basta analisar e entender bem o que escreveu no código.

Answer (score 2):

Json é um formato bem melhor para salvar dados serializados. O Pickle tem vários problemas de segurança e compatibilidade.

```py
# Considerações:
# 1) Isso não é um sistema de login
# 2) Armazenar usuário e senha em um arquivo de texto ou em pickle é um trabalho super porco
from json import dumps, loads

dic = {'Lucas': '1234'}

# Serializando os dados em json e salvando em um arquivo de texto
with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(dumps(dic))

# Lendo dados serializados em json
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    dic_deserializado = loads(f.read())


# Adicionando mais entradas e salvando
dic_deserializado.update({'Xablaus': '4321'})
with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(dumps(dic_deserializado))
```